# Forward declaration of array of QStrings leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, forward-declaration, qstring

In this code I have two forward declarations, a `bool` array and a `QString` array in namesace `NLog`.

`bool` works. `QString` produces a segmentation fault.

Header:

```
class Log : public QObject
{

    explicit Log();
public:
    enum Facility
    {
      third_party_fac,
      test_fac,
      __facility_last_element
    };
    enum Severity
    {
      debug_sev,
      warning_sev,
      critical_sev,
      fatal_sev,
      __severity_last_element
    };
};
namespace NLog
{
    extern bool logging_enabled[Log::__facility_last_element][Log::__severity_last_element];
    extern QString severity_name[Log::__severity_last_element];
};
class LogStaticInitiallizer
{
public:
    LogStaticInitiallizer();
};
static LogStaticInitiallizer initiallizer=LogStaticInitiallizer();
```

Source:

```
QString NLog::severity_name[Log::__severity_last_element];
bool NLog::logging_enabled[Log::__facility_last_element][Log::__severity_last_element];
using NLog::logging_enabled;
using NLog::severity_name;
LogStaticInitiallizer::LogStaticInitiallizer()
{
    qDebug()<<"0";
    qDebug()<<logging_enabled[0][0];
    qDebug()<<severity_name[0];
    qDebug()<<"1";
}
```

it produces

> 0
>
> false

and crashes at QString trace

Comment: `__facility_last_element` and others starting with `__` are reserved identifiers

Comment: could this be *Static Initialization Order Fiasco* ?

Comment: Where do you initialize your arrays?

Comment: @vahancho it seems irrelevant, as `QString` has default ctor

Comment: @ Piotr S. I have only this .cpp and one with main function, which just returns 0.

Comment: @user2136963 yes, and that static `initiallizer` presumably gets initialized (ctor called) before the ctors of elements of QString array are executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Piotr S. said, the problem is that `LogStaticInitiallizer` constructor is called before its initialization in source file.

Also, there is an unrelated to main problem with reserved identifiers starting with `__`. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)